# How to load HTML file containing <template> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-component

I want to re-use my custom web component.  My web pages are primarily defined by HTML files, not Javascript.  Is there any viable way to insert my component into my main file using HTML/Javascript/jQuery?  (I know I could assemble it via server-side programming, but that's far less reusable.)

*Simple Example*

File `widget.html`:

```
<template>
   // some content
</template
```

Main file `main.html`:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
    $("#foo").load("widget.html);  // does not work.
</script>
```

Note that this code fails for only the `<template> ... </template>` portion of any file I try to load. If I place other valid (and even invalid) HTML elements such as `<div>` or `<foobar>`, those elements get inserted into my page.

Comment: See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for "html includes". Strange as it sounds they don't yet exist. You can put that template html in the component's class. Then in your main.html you simply use the component as any other html <div><you-component></you-component></div>. This after customElement.define(html-name, className). Surprisingly easy when you get your head around it.

Comment: @Berniev Yes.  I could just make my template's HTML a Javascript literal in my component class.  But then my non-programming designer cannot easily manipulate and style it.  The whole reason I'm using templates is to separate content and presentation concerns.